# Meteor: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: meteor

I am very new to Meteor. I am doing simple app. 
Here is the problem I have:

```js
Template.newFeedForm.events({
   'submit #new-feed-form'(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       const target = event.target;
       const text = target.text;

       Meteor.call('feeds.insert', text);

       target.text.value = '';
   }
});
```

So I have newFeedForm template and in my feeds.js I have

```js
Meteor.methods({
    'feeds.insert'(text){
        check(text, String);
        //check(hashtag, String);

        // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
        if (! this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        }
        console.log(this.userId);

        // Feeds.insert({
        //     text: text,
        //     owner: this.userId,
        //     username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
        //     createdAt: new Date()
        // });
    }
});
```

I commented out the Feeds.insert here thinking that it causes the problem. Seems it is something different.
Whenever Meteor.call is executed I got this:

```js
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function._.(anonymous function) [as isArguments] (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:1068:30)
    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969:512:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969:531:22
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:157:22)
    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969:530:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969:531:22
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:157:22)
    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969:530:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969:531:22
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:157:22)
```

Have no Idea what is happening.
Here is my repo that reproduces this error:
https://github.com/yerassyl/nurate-meteor

Comment: Are you importing something incorrectly? As given, your code shouldn't be throwing that error. Have you run it through a debugger?

Comment: have you confirmed you're entering your submit handler only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, when errors like this occur (especially when dealing with a Meteor Method) it means you are probably not passing the "correct" data (or the data that you thought you were).

Looking at your form handling code, I noticed that you are never obtaining the textarea text data.

```
const text = target.text;
```

target.text returns the actual textarea DOM object but what you are really after is the value the object contains.  The below code will solve your issue.

```
const text = target.text.value;
```

Comment: why in the world are we getting this exception stack though for unexpected data?! I need a reference spreadsheet just to tell my meteor errors apart

Answer (score 1):

When you use `db.find()` working with meteor. It gives error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` because it return cursor which is reactive data source.

use this `db.find().fetch()` to get data in form of array.

> db.find() -> **It return cursor which is reactive data source**
>
> db.find().fetch() -> **It return array from the cursor**

Comment: Thank you! Solved a huge server side issue for me.