# SendGrid sgMail.send error using coffeescript meteor. Works fine as pure JS

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, sendgrid

The sgMail.send(msg) call produces an error when I code in Coffee. If I leave is as embedded js it works fine.

This is the error:

```
I20190305-07:32:50.195(-8)? Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
I20190305-07:32:50.196(-8)?     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?  => awaited here:
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Promise.await (/Users/paulpedrazzi/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.2.a0r1i6.m5ai8++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:60:12)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Server.apply (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1634:14)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at Server.call (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1603:17)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at MethodInvocation.sendEmail (server/main.coffee:77:12)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1767:12)
I20190305-07:32:50.197(-8)?     at DDP._CurrentMethodInvocation.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1304:12)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at DDPServer._CurrentWriteFence.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:46)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1304:12)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at Promise (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:715:46)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:689:23)
I20190305-07:32:50.198(-8)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `const`s are your problem. In Coffeescript you can just remove them. Removing `const` in JS cannot break previously running code (though adding them could). Here is your sample converted to coffeescript:

```
sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
msg = 
  to: 'test@example.com'
  from: 'test@example.com'
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js'
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>'

sgMail.send(msg)
```

[Here you can see the javascript it is converted to](https://coffeescript.org/#try:sgMail%20%3D%20require('%40sendgrid%2Fmail')%0AsgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)%0Amsg%20%3D%20%0A%20%20to%3A%20'test%40example.com'%0A%20%20from%3A%20'test%40example.com'%0A%20%20subject%3A%20'Sending%20with%20SendGrid%20is%20Fun'%0A%20%20text%3A%20'and%20easy%20to%20do%20anywhere%2C%20even%20with%20Node.js'%0A%20%20html%3A%20'%3Cstrong%3Eand%20easy%20to%20do%20anywhere%2C%20even%20with%20Node.js%3C%2Fstrong%3E'%0A%0AsgMail.send(msg))

The error looks like an infinite loop or recursive function call.

If you converted JS code to Coffeescript, check your indentation, as Coffeescript uses this for blocks rather than braces.

If you can figure out which lines the error is coming from, you can post that code, and from where it is called.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I added your code and have the same error (added above).  So my coffee version was ok. Literally all I'm doing it calling that function on the server.  Very odd.

Comment: And good point.  I assumed const, but maybe it's something else.

Comment: @ppedrazzi The error is from the EJSON library (used by meteor), probably trying to operate on a cyclic object. Here's a [question with the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375420/meteor-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded). It might help, but the error message cannot tell us where the error is coming from, so I suggest filling your code with console.logs until you figure out roughly where it fails.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that  it has to do with ending the meteor method call on the sgMail.send(msg) since if I add a console.log statement as the last line, everything works ok.